Safari handles fit-content dialogs wrapping height: 100% as having no height
I have a HTML dialog element .parent containing an inner div .child. The parent has height: fit-content while the child has height: 100%. In other browsers, the height of the elements are computed as some nonzero value fitting the content of .child. However, in Safari, .child's height is being computed as 0. What's going on here?
In this snippet, I've colored .child's background green. I expect the green to be visible,indicating nonzero height.


.parent {
  height: fit-content;
}

.child {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
<dialog open class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
   </div>
</dialog>




Did you figure this out? I have been also struggling with this in safari. If I don't specify a height in the dialog element, safari treats it as 0, while in the other browsers it will fit the content. If I set height: auto, it kind of works but still doesn't fit all the content as expected but at least it shows some height.

I was also struggling with this issue, if instead of height: 100% on the child element, use min-height: 100% that should work.


.parent {
  height: fit-content;
}

.child {
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
<dialog open class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Content
   </div>
</dialog>



